# Meaning of "a touch of approval"

Tags: meaning

This phrase comes from *The Gambler* by Fyodor Dostoevsky, translated by C. J. Hogarth. Here is the full sentence:

> "But I was an uninvited guest at the luncheon—the General had forgotten to arrange otherwise, or I should have been dispatched to dine at the table d'hote. Nevertheless, I presented myself in such guise that the General looked at me with **a touch of approval**.”

I looked up a Chinese translation, which is my first language, and it says this: "The general took a discontented glimpse at me."

The question is: is "a touch of approval" a negative expression that can be interpreted as *"discontent"* or *"dissatisfied"*?

Comment: I'd say it should be more like a **glimpse of approval or acknowledgement**. It's a positive expression, and not negative.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The same here... It would be great if I can read Russian.

Comment: I would interpret it to mean a small amount of "positive" approval, such as a smile in the individual's direction.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it should be more like a **glimpse of approval** or **acknowledgement**. It's a **positive** expression, and not **negative**.

The full paragraph by the way is here so it definitely indicates a positive outcome:

> Nevertheless, I presented myself in such guise that the General looked
>   at me with a touch of approval; and, though the good Maria Philipovna
>   was for showing me my place, the fact of my having previously met the
>   Englishman, Mr. Astley, saved me, and thenceforward I figured as one
>   of the company.

[Source](http://www.online-literature.com/dostoevsky/the_gambler/1/)

Answer (score 1):

*Touch* here [means](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20touch) a small amount, a hint or suggestion, as in:

> The cake is good, but it needs a **touch** of vanilla.

The narrator is a gate crasher as the luncheon, but that smallest look of approval from the General saves the narrator's place at the table.